# Fedora 37 Update Problem

Tags: linux, fedora

So I decided to install fedora again after several years using the same iso file I had. Now I want to update it and when I type `sudo dnf upgrade` it gives me this:

```
Copr repo for PyCharm owned by phracek          0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:03    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'phracek-PyCharm':
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/phracek/PyCharm/fedora-37-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Failed to connect to copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 242 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/phracek/PyCharm/fedora-37-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Failed to connect to copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 252 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/phracek/PyCharm/fedora-37-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Failed to connect to copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 1750 ms: Network is unreachable]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/phracek/PyCharm/fedora-37-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Failed to connect to copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 1746 ms: Network is unreachable]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'phracek-PyCharm': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Fedora 37 - x86_64                              0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'fedora':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-37&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'fedora': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-37&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]
```

I have little experience with linux and I have no idea how to fix it. I also have to add that my country is sanctioned by fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `[Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]`

That means something is wrong with your network setup; `mirrors.fedoraproject.org` resolves without problem.

The other errors point to similar, but different problems (sounds like a misconfigured proxy?).

This indicates you have a *very* special network setup, and it's likely you'll need to figure out how to configure your network connection to resolve these addresses.

Comment: Now I actually went to http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org AND  https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/phracek/PyCharm/fedora-37-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml. They gave me an error BUT it worked with VPN.

Comment: @SurKhosh they don't give an error for anyone else, so it's really your network or VPN setup